# Count sequences of length $M$ where each elements is between $1$ and $N$ and between two elements the distance is at least $D$

Tags: combinatorics

We have given three integers $N, M, D$, we want to count sequences of length $M$ where each element of the sequence is in the interval $[1, N]$ and each element between $1 \text{ and } N$ is in the sequence at least once, and the distance between two equal elements in the sequences is at least $D$.

It always holds that $D \leq N \leq M$.

For example if $N = 3, M = 4, D = 1$ then one of the 18 valid orders is $\{1, 2, 1, 3 \}$.

What would be the best approach to count those sequences. I tried defining mask to keep the values of the elements inserted at least once, and then another mask for keeping the last D elements in the sequence, however this approach turns out to be very slow, since all numbers can be up to $100$. I don't have big experience in combinatorics, so I don't know which techniques to use here.